# Using Inputs inside Datagrid (wrong values shown)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-admin

I'm using a Datagrid component inside a List. TextFields show correct values but TextInput and SelectInput (I need them to call custom function when selected on the left) has wrong data.

[image: List]

Referring to above attached image:

- in section 1 I should have in TextInput the same value of the following TextField.
- in section 2 I should have the possibility to choose a different option for each row, but at the moment when I change on a record, all records are changed.

Sorry, I'm new on React Admin and I need some help.

---

Edit:

As rightly requested I attach my code (partially cleaned from other).

```
export const ListaFornitori = () => {
    const { data, isLoading, error } = useGetList(
        "fornitori", {
        pagination: {
            page: 1,
            perPage: 100
        }
    },
    );
    if (isLoading) { return <p>Loading</p>; }
    if (error) { return <p>ERROR</p>; }
    return <AutocompleteInput source="id_fornitore" label="Fornitore" choices={data} optionText="rag_soc" />;
};

export const RichiestaMerceModifica = () => {
    return (
        <Edit title={<TitoloSezione />} actions={false}>
            <SimpleForm toolbar={<CustomToolbar />}>
                <List resource="richieste_merce_dettagli">
                    <Datagrid>
                        <ReferenceField source="id_prod" reference="prodotti_acquisto" label="Prodotto">
                            <TextField source="nome" />
                        </ReferenceField>
                        <ReferenceField source="id_prod" reference="prodotti_acquisto" label="Descrizione" link={false}>
                            <TextField source="descr" />
                        </ReferenceField>
                        <TextField source="qta" label="Q.ta" />
                        <ReferenceField reference="prodotti_acquisto" source="id_prod" label="Imp. unitario" link={false}>
                            <TextInput source="imp" />
                        </ReferenceField>
                        <ReferenceField reference="prodotti_acquisto" source="id_prod" label="" link={false}>
                            <FunctionField render={record => `${record.imp} €`} />
                        </ReferenceField>
                        <BooleanField source="ordinato" />
                        <ListaFornitori />
                    </Datagrid>
                </List>
            </SimpleForm>
        </Edit>
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you please share code for the same

Comment: For first section, are you maintaining same state for both the TextField and TextInput?
For second I suppose you are accessing the dropdown via querySelector and have same Id for each row..

Answer (score 0):

Input components take their value based on the source. In your example, each line has one input with the same source, so it makes sense that they all have the same value.

Besides, you're using both a List and an Edit component in the same page, and that's a mistake. Both are page components, taking their parameters from the URL, and there can only be one per page.

to summarize, you're absolutely not in the right direction, and you have misunderstood some fundamental concepts about react-admin. I advise you to read the introductions of each section of the documentation to learn the basics.

Finally, if you want to let users edit content in a datagrid, react-admin has a component for that: EditableDatagrid.

```
const ArtistList = () => (
    <List hasCreate empty={false}>
        <EditableDatagrid
            mutationMode="undoable"
            createForm={<ArtistForm />}
            editForm={<ArtistForm />}
        >
            <TextField source="id" />
            <TextField source="firstname" />
            <TextField source="name" />
            <DateField source="dob" label="born" />
            <SelectField
                source="prof"
                label="Profession"
                choices={professionChoices}
            />
        </EditableDatagrid>
    </List>
);

const ArtistForm = () => (
    <RowForm>
        <TextField source="id" />
        <TextInput source="firstname" validate={required()} />
        <TextInput source="name" validate={required()} />
        <DateInput source="dob" label="born" validate={required()} />
        <SelectInput
            source="prof"
            label="Profession"
            choices={professionChoices}
        />
    </RowForm>
);
```

Comment: I'm new to React-Admin and I admit my faults  For previous code I will use EditableDatagrid as soon as I can. However, I didn't understand how to show in the same page 2 different "page components". For instance if I need to Edit a specific record but below in the same page show a list of related records (from another resource/table). I can't find this kind of example in the official documentation